# Installshield 2008 Professional - Administrator Mode Installation Related Query

Tags: installshield

I am facing an issue regarding registry key locations when trying to install msi in Administrator mode (i.e. msiexec /a msiname /qn).

Our application is 32-bit application. When I am trying to install it on 32-bit as well as 64-bit windows OS using switch 'i' , the 'Uninstall' key is added to desired location. i.e. 
   HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/Currentversion/Uninstall/{ProductCode} - on 32-bit OS

```
HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/Microsoft/Windows/Currentversion/Uninstall/{ProductCode} - on 64-bit OS.
```

but, when I try to execute the same msi in Administrator mode i.e. using switch 'a', on 64-bit machine, the 'Uninstall' key is added to . i.e.

```
HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/Currentversion/Uninstall/{ProductCode}
```

i.e. it is not added under WOW6432node.

The issue with this is that when I uninstall the msi which I had installed using switch 'a' , the uninstall key is not deleted from registry (as it is being searched in WOW6432node but not found)

So, when I install the same msi next time, the 'EstimatedSize' key value keeps on increasing as the key was not deleted during previous uninstallation.
Due to this, in control panel, for my application, the size is displayed wrongly.